# = vs === operator for Boolean expressions

Tags: javascript, boolean

Again this will be a bit of a newbie question, im just trying to get clear in my head how javascript interprets Boolean expressions.

okay so say i have the following bit of code:

```
var boolean = true;
while(boolean){
boolean === false;
};
```

This goes into an infinite loop due to the use of the identical === operator. Is this because javascript stores the boolean expression "true" as digit "1" while using the shorthand expression while(boolean). So is while(boolean) actually interpreted as while(boolean === 1) rather than while(boolean === true)?

Comment: @Izzy: No, in this case the confusion is between `=` and `===` (and other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

= is the assignment operator. Writing

```
var bool = false;
```

means "set the variable named 'bool' to 'false'"

While === is a strict equality operator. Writing

```
bool === false;
```

checks if the variable 'bool' holds the exact value 'false'. It means "Does the variable 'bool' hold the value 'false'?"

It will return a boolean: true if bool holds the value false, false otherwise. In this case it returns true.

It goes into an infinite loop because 'bool' never changes value. To set it to true, use =

```
bool = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is this because javascript stores the boolean expression "true" as digit "1" while using the shorthand expression while(boolean).

No.

> So is while(boolean) actually interpreted as while(boolean === 1) rather than while(boolean === true)?

No.

It loops forever because you're doing nothing to change the value of your `boolean` variable within the loop. The line

```
boolean === false;
```

...has no effect; you're doing a *comparison* and not storing the result of it anywhere.

You seem to have `=` and `===` confused. They do completely different things. Here's a rundown:

- `=` is the *assignment operator*. It's what you use to assign values to things. `boolean = true;` *assigns* the value `true` to the variable `boolean`.
- `===` is the *strict equality operator*. It's used to see if two things are strictly equal ("strictly" = "without type coercion"). So `a === b` evaluates `true` if `a` and `b` contain values with the same type that are equivalent.
- `==` is the *loose equality operator*. It's used to see if two things are loosely equal ("loosely" = "with type coercion"). So `a == b` will evaluate `true` if `a === b` would be true *or* if `a` and `b` have different types but type coercion can convert one or the other to be the other's type. (The rules for this are complex, but for instance `"" == 0` evaluates `true` because `""` coerces to `0`.)